# Duplicate reportable field in separate Team Project Collections

Tags: tfs, reporting, data-warehouse

I have two team project collections: TPC1 and TPC2. TPC1 has a custom reportable field used for tracking product releases. TPC2 does not have this field, but I would like to add it.

Here is an example:

- TPC: TPC1
- Custom field ref name: Company.ProductId
- Reporting Attribute: Dimension

- TPC: TPC2
- Custom field ref name: Company.ProductId
- Reporting Attribute: Dimension

Will adding is field cause a schema conflict (blocked fields) in the TFS Warehouse?

As always, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not a conflict in the TFS Warehouse as long as the fields have the same definition (i.e. they are of the same type, same friendly/reference name, same reportable attribute).

Comment: Awesome! All of those conditions are true in my case, so it sounds like I should be good to go. Thanks!